# Get main gmail account username in Android < 2.0

Tags: android, gmail

For retrieving the accounts (information) in Android versions since 2.0 you can use the AccountManager that has been introduced in Android 2.0.

But now I have the problem I want to maintain compatibility with atleast Android 1.6, is there any way to retrieve account information in Android 1.6?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. download the framework.jar from: 
   http://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_opt_com.google.android/... 
   and add it to you build path. this is some sort of an interface to the 
   Google device functions.
2. call the method:

   com.google.android.googlelogin.GoogleLoginServiceHelper.getAccount(Activity activity, int requestCode, boolean requireGoogle);

   where: 
   Activity:  is your Activity which get the result in the 
   onActivityResult() 
   requestCode: your code 
   requireGoogle: should be true

   EX. GoogleLoginServiceHelper.getAccount(mActivity, 123, true);

3.override the onActivityResult() like:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
    Intent data) { 
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
            if(requestCode == 123){ 
                System.out.println(resultCode); 
                String key = "accounts"; 
                System.out.println(key + ":" + 
    Arrays.toString(data.getExtras().getStringArray(key))); 
                String accounts[] = data.getExtras().getStringArray(key); 
                if(accounts != null){ 
                   int i = 0; 
                   for(String ac : accounts){  //each account is the full 
    email address registered with this device 
                        System.out.println("ac " + i + "=" + ac); 
                         i++; 
                   } 
                } 
       }
```

original post is [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/7a6bf77910ca31e0/7a7659d61a89fa41%3Flnk%3Dgst%26q%3Dhow%2Bcan%2BI%2Bget%2Bthe%2BGoogle%2Baccount%2Bor%2BGmail%2Baddress%2Bfrom%2Bthe%2Bphone%237a7659d61a89fa41&usg=AFQjCNHjHC0BihXAkabib4ScyoqHPc3w4Q)

Comment: also add the permission to manifest file:
<uses-permission 
android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH"></ 
uses-permission>

Comment: I don't see a GoogleLoginServiceHelper in this jar.
There is a GoogleLoginServiceBlockingHelper however, but which doesn't have the getAccount method

Comment: You have to download a previous revision, search for one that contains the GoogleLoginServiceHelper, I found it and it works :D

Comment: Addendum to the above, and to future finders: the last framework.jar with GoogleLoginServiceHelper is here: 

http://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_opt_com.google.android/blob/e34c847d89accef6129d8de814f31f396e021098/framework.jar

Committed September 02, 2009

Comment: I am getting accounts as null in onActivityResult, I am trying with android2.2, any one have idea about this?