# Get Configured Email Account In Android 1.5

Tags: android

I need to Detect My android Device is configured with email or not in Android 1.5.  i have Seen the class AccountManager but it is useful for only 2.0 not 1.5. Please any one tell what is class for 1.5 to Detect the Email Client of Device

Answer (score 0):

see : [Get main gmail account username in Android < 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360926/get-main-gmail-account-username-in-android-2-0)

get the git repository and check out the version with tag:"android-1.5"
(the HEAD version has no GoogleLoginServiceHelper class)

Hope this helps.