# Retrieve Primary account name to send the mail in android 2.1

Tags: android, email, sendmail

i am developing an application where i want to send the mail to number of receptions using my own API.
i had achieve to send mail them, but for that i had hard coded my Email ID and Password.
now i want to use the users inbuilt Primary account to send the mail from his own android phone.
i found something like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038333/how-do-i-retrieve-the-logged-in-google-account-on-android-phones). but i am not getting how to use this and it is not going in the if statement.
is there any  other way to achieve this. please solve my problem.

Thanks in advance

AutoMailActivity.java

```
public class AutoMailActivity  extends Activity 
{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step1");
    final Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.send);
    final EditText address;
    final EditText subject;
    final EditText emailtext;

    address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailaddress);

    subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailsubject);

    emailtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailtext);

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final String email1 = emailtext.getText().toString();
            final String sub = subject.getText().toString();
            final String adrs = address.getText().toString();

            try {    
                AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step2");


               GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("example@gmail.com","mypassword");

                AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step3");
                sender.sendMail(sub,email1,"example@gmail.com", adrs);   
                AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step4");
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                 AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step5");
                Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);   
            } 

        }
    });
```

Now
GmailSender.java

```
public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator
 {   
    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";   
    private String user;   
    private String password;   
    private Session session;   

    static {   
         AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step1.1");
        Security.addProvider(new com.provider.JSSEProvider());   
    }  

    public GMailSender(String user, String password) {  
         AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step1.2");
        this.user = user;   
        this.password = password;   

        Properties props = new Properties();   
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step1.3");
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);   
        AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step1.4");
    }   

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
    }   

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {   
        try{
             AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step1.5");
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session); 
        AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step1.6");
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
        AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step1.7");
        message.setSubject(subject);   
        message.setDataHandler(handler);  
        AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step1.8");



        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
        {
            AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step1.9");
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
            Transport.send(message); 
            AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step2.1");
        }
        else 
        {
            AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step2.2");
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));  
            Transport.send(message); 
        AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step2.3");
        }

        AppLogger.LogError("Reached to Step2.4");
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            AppLogger.LogError(e.getMessage());
        }




    }   


    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {   
        private byte[] data;   
        private String type;   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
        }   

        public void setType(String type) {   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public String getContentType() {   
            if (type == null)   
                return "application/octet-stream";   
            else  
                return type;   
        }   

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {   
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
        }   

        public String getName() {   
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
        }   

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {   
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
        }   
    }   
}  

}
}
```

Comment: hey pra.. can you eloberate more where exactly you are stucked. and if possible please paste your code here..

Comment: @Amol Bhanushali hi Amol, please see the updated code and suggest me what to do

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to retrieve accounts.

```
    private String getAccounts(Context context) {
        String accountNames = "";
        try {
            AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
            Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccounts();
            for (Account account : accounts) {
                accountNames += "," + account.name;
            }
            if (accountNames.length() > 0)
                accountNames = accountNames.substring(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception getAccounts : " + e);
        }
        return accountNames;
    }
```