# Authenticate user in Android

Tags: android, security, authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I retrieve the logged in Google account on android phones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038333/how-do-i-retrieve-the-logged-in-google-account-on-android-phones)

I am creating an application which needs authentication. I don't know anything about client authentication. I will be grateful if anybody could help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java there is a library at

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/downloads/detail?name=google-api-java-client-1.6.0-beta.zip You can download it use it

Answer (score 1):

It's best practice to use [`AccountManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) for client authentication

To know how to use the `AccountManager`, [look here for example code.](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/AndroidAccountManager)