# Get android logged in google account

Tags: java, android

I would like to know how could I get currently logged in google account on android phone by code.

I am aware of [How do I retrieve the logged in Google account on android phones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038333/how-do-i-retrieve-the-logged-in-google-account-on-android-phones). However, in this question all available accounts on the phone are retrieved. How is it possible to distinguish the logged in one?