# Determine Users on Android 4.2 Device

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, multi-user

Is there any way to determine if there are other users installed on the device or if the device is being used a single user tablet?

Along those lines is it possible to get the name, id, or Google account of the current user?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question, this code will return all the Google accounts of the current user:

```
    AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(context);
    Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
```

You will also need this permission in your manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" /
```

Comment: So there is no way to use the AccountManager to see the accounts across the entire device?

Comment: The SDK docs are very helpful. You should try them: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

Answer (score 0):

For account information see the [`AccountManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) class. This should show you the accounts on the device and allow you to determine other users, etc.

For details, check out the following post (and others like it...):

[How do I retrieve the logged in Google account on android phones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038333/how-do-i-retrieve-the-logged-in-google-account-on-android-phones)