# Is there way I can make user to enter Google account and password before using all the apps?

Tags: android, google-signin, google-account

I am newbie in this kind of task from the work and hope anyone can help me.

We are currently developing custom tablets for our customers with android OS.
But my manager wants me to develop webpage/ app that we can bring google login page to make customers enter their username and password before use all the apps in Android OS. (It does not mean only app I developed, but also google chrome and any other basic apps in Android OS.)
Additionally, once customer successfully log-in then we don't re-ask google account again next time.

Is there way I can develop that? Or codes?
In my opinion, it is totally impossible...

Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: Implement a service to listen for device boot event using [`BOOT_COMPLETED`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19856267/593709) and when all set, check all the [accounts logged-in in device](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4039018/593709), check if any google account is there, if not, ask them to login.

Comment: @AdilSoomro Thank you for your reply. Could you give me tutorial for this? I am very newbiew at here so. :(

Comment: You won't find tutorial exactly matching to your requirements, but I've added two links in my first comment, that'll help you set up your path to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

use firebase authentication (you can make users enter google account or email password) and let the authentication activity take you to an activity where there are image's of all the app and when clicking on the image the app opens.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you give me tutorial for this? I am very newbiew at here so. :(

Comment: go to firebase.google.com and create an account  search google and u will find much of tutorial, here is the firebase documentations. if this is the answer your seeking please hit the true signe button on the left https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin