# Is it possible to fetch google account details of the account logged in on the android phone in an app?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to fetch the details without the user actually signing in? 
Can we directly fetch the details from the google account on the phone?

I am trying to create an app with drawer functionality and want to display the logged in google user's profile picture, name and email (like seen on playstore etc.)

The solution on the similar question doesn't work for me. - I get an empty list using @shylendra's answer on android 8.0 and 8.1, didnt test it below that.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: Please describe more specifically about your problem. What do you want to do with it? Have you searched about it?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

Comment: Do some research before posting old and repeated questions

Comment: updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to fetch the details without the user actually signing in?

Yes, You can by using [AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4039018/2462531)

```
AccountManager manager = (AccountManager) getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
Account[] list = manager.getAccounts();
String gmail = null;

for(Account account: list)
{
    if(account.type.equalsIgnoreCase("com.google"))
    {
        gmail = account.name;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but I get an empty list even after giving permission.

Comment: @HarshadLoya Are you using real device or emulator? Did you sign in with Google account on mobile?

Comment: @shylendra - Tried both, and yes I am signed in with google account on my phone, infact there are over 10 accounts I am signed in into other than google account.  Refer this question, i have added code as well and found out a little more : https://stackoverflow.com/q/48875946/5093418

Answer (score 0):

Try this!!!

**AccountManager** helps to get the details of an account associated with the phone

```
AccountManager manager = (AccountManager) getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
Account[] list = manager.getAccounts();
```

Add these permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: I tried it, but I get an empty list even after giving permission.